# MongoDB find documents that have any of the list occurred in list field

Tags: mongodb

Say I have a collection *book*, like this:

```
{
   name:"xxxx",
   tags:["thriller", "novel", "modern"]
}
```

How can I query all the books that have **at least one** of the tags: "novel","music" ?  Is there a way like :

```
db.inventory.find( { tags: { $containsAny: ["novel","music"] } } )
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The other answer in the marked dupe solves your problem with the `$in` operator as `db.inventory.find( { tags: { $in: ["novel", "music"] } } )`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `$in` operator. You can query to get all the books that have at least one of the tags. query like

```
db.inventory.find({tags: {$in:['novel', 'music']}})
```